# Are there any files created and or broadened by the system besides mail and logs?

Tags: disk, inode, size, stability

Are there any files created and or broadened by the system besides mail and logs?

AFAIK, the only files that are created and/or broadened by the system in default are `/var/mail/` files and `/var/log/` files (broadened by means of file size).

To cope with that I've redirected `/dev/null on files in these directories.

But are there more files besides mail and logs that I should worry that they'll be created and broadened by the Linux system itself, throughout time?

Comment: Creating symlinks to `/dev/null` is probably not enough; you also have to deactivate `logrotate`.

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you desribe what you want to achieve instead?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to save disk space by reducing automatically created data that I don't need, so I try to find out what are the places to look for it, an then `truncate` these in a suitable way.

Comment: See, this could be a job for `logrotate`; instead of deactivating it you can reduce the size and number of files, enable compression (if not already set), or discard old logs altogether. But speaking from my experience the effect may possibly be in a range of few megabytes, you shouldn't expect much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading up on the [Unix filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem).

The `/var/` directory holds frequently changing files. The `/etc/` directory holds configurations that don't typically grow too much. the `/usr/` directory holds OS files that don't change too much outside of system upgrades. If you have third-party applications running off of `/srv/` or `/opt/`, those directories may grow.

Comment: As it's a minimal server environment (Ubuntu-Nginx-SSHguard-Postfix-WordPress) with a few sites and **no** system customizations or third party software I don't think much will change in `/var/`. I also `find /var/log -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` on `/var/mail` and `/var/logs/`.

Answer (score 0):

The system updates create new files which may be kept.

Comment: I only use `unattended-upgrades` usually, and only for security upgrades. Do you think these changes would probably be significant for a minimal Ubuntu-Nginx-SSHguard-Postfix-WordPress **minimal** server environment? It's a 5 bucks VPS with 20GB SSD space. Also, I run `find /var/log -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` on `/var/mail` and `/var/logs/`.

Comment: @Arcticooling You could delete the files after upgrades. I do not know, though, what the official way is for doing that.